# Is it possible to find the exact value of this

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find the exact value of the infinite series ?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n+1}$$

I have no any idea.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: By wolfram it doesn't look to have a closed form:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5Einfty+2%5En%2F%28%281%2Bsqrt%282%29%29%5En%2B1%29

Comment: You could certainly bound it from above by comparison to the geometric sequence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}} \right)^n$$.

Comment: Even the seemingly simpler $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{3^n+1}$$ apparently has no closed form, at least per wolframalpha.